# Add Shortcode to include a PHP file which includes HTML + JavaScript to use inside Wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I created a PHP file which includes HTML and JavaScript for a dropdown widget and output estimated shipping price and time.

I'm trying to create a shortcode to use for Wordpress "shortcode" widget. But when I try to save the page, this error pops up everytime: `Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.`
[image: Error when saving]

Moreover, after saving, the dropdown jumps to the top of the page, and at the section where I placed the shortcode, value `1` is showing.
[image: Dropdown jumps to top]
[image: Value "1" is showing]

Here's my code inside function.php

```
function shippingcal(){
return include ("KB/widget/shipping-calculator.php");
};

add_shortcode('sc_shippingcal', 'shippingcal');
```

Inside my PHP file does contain JavaScript with many variables and functions, I don't know if that's the problem here or not though.

Comment: `Value "1" showing?` - yes, because that's what a successful `include` returns by default. Your `KB/widget/shipping-calculator.php` script itself would need to `return` the content you want to return out of your `shippingcal` callback function.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for clarifying that! But why is it pushing the element to the top of everything else though? Is there any better way to include php files inside Wordpress page/post editor?

Comment: That is also because your include file doesn't return the content - but writes it to the output buffer directly.

Answer (score 0):

"Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response." usually this message comes when you have a lot of post revisions. try clearing revisions and then try to update.
you can clear post revisions via "wp optimize"  plugin.
Note: Make sure to make a backup before using wp optimize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).